# How to remove items from an arraylist without shrinking the list

Tags: java

I have a case where I am using the ArrayList to keep a list of items that are keyed by their position in the list.  Other objects reference the ArrayList items by their position.  If I delete one of the items from the list, I don't want the list to shrink because that would invalidate all other references to items in the list (e.g. item 2 is now in position 1).  My solution to the shrinking array list problem is to null the position in the arraylist so that the list will not shrink.  I am curious whether this will free the memory formerly held by the item at that position.

If there is a better way to accomplish this requirement, I would like to know about it.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code to test if your approach does what you would expect it to?

Answer (score 7):

Given your goal of consistently referencing items by a given key (the index) over a long period what you want is actually a Dictionary or Hashtable, the ArrayList is the wrong data structure for your purposes, and using one in this manner is very dangerous indeed. It just takes one element being removed somewhere by someone and bingo bango all references are wrong, worse than an error they'll be getting incorrect data.

Use the right data structure for this, use a data structure made to associate elements to a given key, which is a Dictionary or Hashtable.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, the memory will be freed up if there are no other references to the object. You won't really have control over how and when it is freed up, although you could run a gc, which is not good practice and doesn't guarantee you it will be cleaned up.

Note that ArrayList is not synchronized. You state that you have multiple objects referencing the ArrayList - you will need to synchronize to avoid concurrent modification.

Are you tied to ArrayList? Is order important to you, or just that you have a consistent reference to the item in the list?

Answer (score 0):

If `ArrayList` in java works like an `ArrayList` in .NET it's just a wrapper around an array. If the internal array is too small it will allocate a new larger array and copy all items to the new array. That procedure will repeat each time the internal array becomes too small.

Conclusion:

1. The contained object will be freed (unless someone else is referencing it) when you set the `array[mypos] = null`.
2. The internal array will continue to grow if you keep adding new items.